# Сериализация в XML результата LINQ to SQL запроса

Tags: c#, xml, serialize, linq

Добрый день. Возникла задача из сабжа.

На данный момент написал простой метод:

```
public static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(obj.GetType());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
    dcs.WriteObject(writer, obj);
    writer.Close();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Все работает, но: в БД таблица, запись из которой сериализуется, имеет связи по Id с несколькими другими таблицами. В результирующем XML нужно получить не Id, а, допустим, Name из этих связанных таблиц.

Возможно ли это сделать штатными средствами? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хм. А как выглядит ваш класс (`obj`), который вы фактически сериализуете? Если он берётся из LINQ-запроса, покажите нужную часть запроса.

**Обновление**

То есть это entity? Тогда почему бы не сделать неявный join:

```
from s in context.Session where s.Id = _id
select new { ..., Name = s.ForeignEntity.Name }
```

(где `ForeignEntity` — navigation property)?

Comment: @VladD, так класс из DataContext...или я чего то не понял? работаю с dbml.

запрос 
    (from s in _context.Session where s.Id == _id_ select s).FirstOrDefault();